# Assigning DB2 databases to 32-bit ODBC on a 64-bit machine via command line

Tags: excel, db2, odbc

I'm attempting to connect to a DB2 database through Excel (From Other sources > From Microsoft Query) on a 64-bit machine.  On a 32-bit machine, this has been as simple as just opening db2cmd and running DB2 -f databases.txt (which contains a list of our databases catalogs them, generally via 'Catalog database Foo as Bar at node Foobar', then 'Catalog system odbc data source Bar') and everything is correctly in the list.

However, on the 64-bit machine, Excel appears to be checking the 32-bit ODBC connections, which does not contain the databases.  Is there a way I need to catalog the databases in order to populate them into the 32-bit ODBC list?  I can go in and assign them by hand, but the entire point here is to automate the process, so a command line solution is preferred.

Comment: To me this looks like an Excel problem, not DB2. You can install the 32-bit DB2 client on a 64-bit Windows system to work around it. I don't think you can have both 32- and 64-bit DB2 client on Windows though.

Comment: That workaround seems to be remedying the issue.  Here's hoping my client doesn't need the 64-bit DB2 client specifically.  Crossing my fingers and waiting to hear back from him :)